# How to implement the Twitter oAuth twitter-api-typescript-sdk example for more than one user

Tags: typescript, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

This [example](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-api-typescript-sdk/blob/main/examples/oauth2-callback_pkce_s256.ts) uses a global 'Client' (see L19), which works if you plan to only ever serve one user.
In practice, usually multiple users are hitting the server concurrently. How is this usually handled?

In `app.get("/callback")` ~Twitter~ X only provides a const `{ code, state }`

The **state** is just a `A random string you provide to verify against CSRF attacks`. **code** is used to obtain the user's `request token`. Should I store that in a cookie? database or user session?
Should I create a new `authClient` for every user request?